# How to check if database creation in LocalDB is finished

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, localdb, ef-core-3.1

I work on a project with uses SQL Server as database together with Entity Framework Core 3.1. For the unit tests / integration tests we use LocalDB.

To ensure the LocalDB database is in the correct migration state, we drop and recreate the test database.

This looks something like this:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    new SqlCommand("USE MASTER", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

    try
    {
        new SqlCommand($"ALTER DATABASE [MyTestDb] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
        new SqlCommand($"DROP DATABASE [MyTestDb]", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        // We get an error if there is no database. This happens the very first time a test gets executed on a machine
    }

    new SqlCommand($"CREATE DATABASE [MyTestDb];", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
    new SqlCommand($"ALTER DATABASE [MyTestDb] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
    new SqlCommand($"ALTER DATABASE [MyTestDb] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT  ON;", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
}

using (var creationConnection = new SqlConnection(@$"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=MyTestDb"))
{
    creationConnection.Open(); // <-- Problematic exception here

    using (var context = new MyDbContext(/*some DbContextOptions here... */))
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

This will throw an exception on `creationConnection.Open();` with following message:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "MyTestDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user ''.

If I add a `Thread.Sleep(10_000);` between the two using blocks, no exception will be thrown.

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    new SqlCommand("USE MASTER", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();

    try
    {
        new SqlCommand($"ALTER DATABASE [MyTestDb] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
        new SqlCommand($"DROP DATABASE [MyTestDb]", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        // We get an error if there is no Database. This happens the very first time a test gets executed on a machine
    }

    new SqlCommand($"CREATE DATABASE [MyTestDb];", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
    new SqlCommand($"ALTER DATABASE [MyTestDb] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
    new SqlCommand($"ALTER DATABASE [MyTestDb] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT  ON;", sqlConnection).ExecuteNonQuery();
}

Thread.Sleep(10_000); // <-- exception will NOT be thrown 

using (var creationConnection = new SqlConnection(@$"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=MyTestDb"))
{
    creationConnection.Open(); 

    using (var context = new MyDbContext(/*some DbContextOptions here... */))
    {
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

I assume the database `MyTestDb` is not ready on `creationConnection.Open();` and throws an error.

Is there a way to check if the database creation is finished?

Comment: I literally hate to tell you, but have you considered just doing SOMETHING (stupid little SQL) and check for exactly this error that you give? That is the most simple solution. Open in loop, 1 second delay or half a second between tries. Try/catch until it goes through.

Comment: Why are you assuming the database isn't ready at creationConnection.Open();? These aren't asynchronous tasks - they should be done by the time execution advances to the next statement.

Comment: @TomTom I'm ashamed but that didn't cross my mind. You are absolutely right.

Comment: @mason I thought this as well but I tested it and my LocalDB needs about 5 sec between creation and beeing ready for connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT [collation_name] FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyTestDb';
```

If collation_name has a value (is not null), the database is online.